# Custom Directory Icon Swift

Tags: swift, macos, icons, nsfilemanager

I have the code:

```
do {
    try manager.createDirectory(atPath: appDir!.appendingPathComponent(path).path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
} catch {
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

How do I add a custom icon to the directory (like Dropbox, Creative Cloud, etc.)? Do I add it as an attribute?

Comment: Search it for yourself.  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bosx%5D+folder+icon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it!

```
NSWorkspace.shared().setIcon(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "customFolder"), forFile: appDir!.appendingPathComponent("/Files").path, options: NSWorkspaceIconCreationOptions.excludeQuickDrawElementsIconCreationOption)
```

Use that.

Comment: Does it changes the app icon or the directory icon?

Comment: @LeoDabus directory icon for a certain path.

Comment: Your code doesn't show any pah

Comment: @LeoDabus I put my full code there.

Comment: xcode9: NSWorkspace.shared.setIcon(NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("iconName")), forFile:[repalceMeWithPath], options: NSWorkspace.IconCreationOptions.excludeQuickDrawElementsIconCreationOption)